# TFS vNext the reference to external elements from the source named 'dbref.dacpac' could not be resolved, because no such source is loaded

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, build, vnext

I am currently trying to automate one of our build processes using TFS 2017's vNext build process.

I have a database solution as part of the system that contains two databases db1 and db2. db1 references db2 but db2 references nothing.

A post build step on the db1 project use sqlpackage.exe to compare it with a previously built version and produce a change script. The command for which looks like:

```
"sqlpackage.exe" /a:script /sf:"d:\Builds\1\a\db1\db1.dacpac" /tf:"d:\Builds\1\s\\Databases\Current Live Versions\db1.dacpac" /op:"d:\Builds\1\s\\bin\Release\Sql\db1.sql" /tdn:db1
```

When built from Visual Studio this works fine, however TFS vNext gives the following error

```
EXEC(0,0): Error SQL0: The reference to external elements from the source named 'db2.dacpac' could not be resolved, because no such source is loaded.
```

I've set Suppress Reference Warnings to "True" and this has had no effect.

Anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Could you share your vNext build defintion?

Comment: Can you share the entire build logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've solved it.. seems the location of referenced files used absolute rather than relative paths within the dacpacs, but because the build user is unable to access the directory that the "Current Live Versions" version of the dacpac was built from it gives this error...

Once I gave the Build User permissions to access this folder it all works fine.